# Code Not Updating Database, but print_r shows that everything should work?

Tags: php

Here's my code. For some reason print_r() will show information, however the database does not have entries added to it, when I try this method of adding multiple variables to the database, it doesn't actually update the organization table:

```
 <?php
include "mysql_config.php";
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
$result = mysql_select_db($db);

$orgname = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['orgname']));
$add1 = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['add1']));
$add2 = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['add2']));
$city = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['city']));
$state = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['state']));
$zip = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['zip']));
$url = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['url']));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['email']));
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['phone']));
$contact = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['contact']));
$hours = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['hours']));
$culture = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_map('html2txt', $_POST['culture']));
$service = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_map('html2txt', $_POST['service']));
$category = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_map('html2txt', $_POST['category']));
if (isset($_FILES["file"]['name'])  && ($_FILES['file']['name'] !== '')) {
$file = $orgname."/".basename($_FILES['file']['name']);   
mkdir("./".$orgname);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file);
}
else {
    $file = '';
}

$notes = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['notes']));
$description = mysql_real_escape_string(html2txt($_POST['description']));

print_r($orgname);
print_r($state);
print_r($hours);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO organization (org_name, add_1, add_2, city, state, zip, url, email, phone, contact, hours, file_loc, notes, desc)
             VALUES('".$orgname.", ".$add1.", ".$add2.", ".$city.", ".$state.", ".$zip.", ".$url.", ".$email.", ".$phone.", ".$contact.", ".$hours.", ".$file.", ".$notes.", ".$description."')");

?>
```

Here's the error:

Invalid query: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error here:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO organization (org_name, add_1, add_2, city, state, zip, url, email, phone, contact, hours, file_loc, notes, desc)
             VALUES('".$orgname.", ".$add1.", ".$add2.", ".$city.", ".$state.", ".$zip.", ".$url.", ".$email.", ".$phone.", ".$contact.", ".$hours.", ".$file.", ".$notes.", ".$description."')");
```

you are not surrounding each one with quotes

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO organization (org_name, add_1, add_2, city, state, zip, url, email, phone, contact, hours, file_loc, notes, desc)
             VALUES('".$orgname."', '".$add1."', '".$add2."', '".$city."', '".$state."', '".$zip."', '".$url."'.....)";
```

I'm assuming they are all test in here.

**UPDATE:** for debuging

save your query in a variable, print it, then show us:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO organization ....."; // your query

echo $sql; // show us.
```

Comment: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', '' at line 2

Is the response I get.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing any error checking on the query. Use `mysql_error()` to see what goes wrong.

In this specific case, the query probably fails because `desc` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Add backticks around the field name:

```
`desc`
```

or use a different column name.

Comment: Invalid query: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1